# How can I make it where it doesn't divide by 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the average of the word length. How can I prevent it from getting a zero division error?

```
def main():
    allwords = []
    while True:
        words = input("Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: ")
        if not words:
            break
        allwords.extend(words.split())
    average = sum(len(words) for words in allwords) / len(allwords)
    print("There were {:.2f} words".format(len(allwords)))
    print("Average word length {:.2f}".format(average))    
main()
```

Comment: Test for `if not allwords:` and behave differently when it's empty? Not clear what you want to do in that case, but that's how it goes.

Comment: well I tried your way and I still got an error. Also yeah when the input is empty I get the error

Comment: You definitely didn't get that error if the `if not allwords:` check prevented `average = sum(len(words) for words in allwords) / len(allwords)` and `print("Average word length {:.2f}".format(average))` from running (by doing something else and `return`ing early, or by only doing the `average` stuff in an attached `else:` case). Alternatively, *controlling* those two lines by *only* running them inside an `if allwords:` check gets the same result.

Comment: could you show me what you mean because I'm still getting the error

Comment: I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70040528/364696). Your problem is really just handling the "the user didn't input any words" case, and the solution is not to compute an average when you have no words.

Comment: Sidenote: `words` should be `word` here: `sum(len(words) for words in allwords)`

Answer (score 1):

The `average` only makes sense when there is at least one word; when it's empty, you're trying to compute `0 / 0`, which doesn't work. So don't compute or display the `average` when `allwords` is empty:

```
def main():
    allwords = []
    while True:
        words = input("Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: ")
        if not words:
            break
        allwords.extend(words.split())
    # Moved average computation lower so only one if needed
    print("There were {} words".format(len(allwords)))
    if allwords:  # Only run contents when you got at least one word
        average = sum(len(words) for words in allwords) / len(allwords)
        print("Average word length {:.2f}".format(average))    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to check if `allwords` contains something before continuing:

```
def main():
    allwords = []
    while True:
        words = input("Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: ").strip()
        if not words:
            break
        allwords.extend(words.split())
    print("There were {:.2f} words".format(len(allwords)))
    if allwords:
        average = sum(len(words) for words in allwords) / len(allwords)
        print("Average word length {:.2f}".format(average))
main()
```

Comment: when I try this the print doesn't show

Comment: @codenerd: Because you didn't actually provide a line of words, and this code doesn't output anything when you provide no words.

Comment: Yes, this code skips the print lines. You could make it so that they are not in the `if` statement (though printing `average` would then be pointless), or add an `else` which has different output if the word list was empty. I moved the first `print` which probably means it now does what you want.